# Redmine REST api [update status]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am looking at a way to automate bug tracking with test tools. I found:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_ruby

which describes a way to interact with the REST api in Redmine.
Following it I am able to create/update/destroy issues, but update just simple fields like subject or description.(can't update status or priority)

I can't find a way to change the status of a bug.
All the the fields i can't update are "?structures(with attributes)?".
Has someone managed to do it and what could i have been doing worng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've cloned the repository and started looking through the code.

There is a line in the Issues#update action that shows that it might be a permissions problem.

```
@allowed_statuses = @issue.new_statuses_allowed_to(User.current)
```

Ensure that the user has permissions to change status and priority for a given issue.

I've added an example of all fields for an Issue from one of my projects.

```
id: 83, 
tracker_id: 2, 
project_id: 8, 
subject: "Comments", 
description: "Add comments to the trace on list and on graph view...", 
due_date: nil, 
category_id: nil, 
status_id: 1, 
assigned_to_id: 1, 
priority_id: 4, 
fixed_version_id: nil, 
author_id: 1, 
lock_version: 0, 
created_on: "2012-01-23 14:04:11", 
updated_on: "2012-01-23 14:04:11", 
start_date: "2012-01-23", 
done_ratio: 0, 
estimated_hours: nil, 
parent_id: nil, 
root_id: 83, 
lft: 1, 
rgt: 2, 
is_private: false
```

Comment: No, which repository are you speaking about?

Comment: The Redmine source code. [Here's](https://github.com/redmine/redmine) the git repo. Make sure you are looking at the appropriate branch for the Redmine version you use.

Comment: The user using the api is allowed to manage the project. When loged in using the browser it can change all needed things. With the API I can't/don't know how to change fields which are in classes. For example "issue.status" is a IssueStatus class.

Comment: Try setting `@issue.status_id` or `@issue.priority_id`.

Comment: I've added an example of all fields for an Issue from one of my projects to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you, i had to set @issue.status_id. (Before i was trying to set @issue.status.id)